# How can i use Viola Jones Algorithm to detect the Face as a region of interest and crop it till the rectangle box?

Tags: computer-vision, face-detection, roi, image-preprocessing, viola-jones

I want to detect the face in the video frame and remove the other elements such as background etc. and just want to focus on the facial region, for this i need to use viola jones algorithm, czn anyone give me a hint or suitable answer for this.

```
import cv2
import sys
imagep='6.jpg'#sys.argv[1]
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
i=cv2.imread(imagep)
gray=cv2.imread(imagep,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
f=face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray,scaleFactor=1.1,minNeighbors=5,minSize=(30,30),flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE)
print("Found {0} faces!".format(len(f)))
for(x,y,w,h) in f:
  cv2.rectangle(i,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(0,255,0),2)
  cv2.imshow("Faces found",i)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Answer (score -1):

Once you have the upper left and and bottom right coordinates of the rectangle in which the face is contained, You can just crop the original image on the basis of those coordinates. Let's suppose initial image is stored in the frame variable, follow the code

```
face = face_recognition.detectMultiScale(frame, scaleFactor = 1.8, minNeighbors = 5) #detects coordinates of face
resultant_image = frame[face[0][1] : (face[0][1] + face[0][3]),face[0][0] : (face[0][0] + face[0][2]), :] # gives you cropped image
```

Comment: In 'face_recognition.detectMultiScale()' part, is the Face_recognition part an object or import file? I edited the question to include my code